# Clojure Program Doesn't Work After Compiling

Tags: oracle, clojure

I have a simple Clojure program that queries an Oracle database and prints out results in a comma delimited format. This program works just fine running it normally through Clojure.main. I want to compile this program and followed the instructions from here:

http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html#Compiling

I compiled and ran another simple program using this method described just fine. So I don't think this has anything to do with this method of compiling. This program compiles just fine but when I attempt to run the compiled class it returns this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted
>   Resultset
>           at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:47)
>           at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
>           at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:440)
>           at clojure.core$seq__4245.invoke(core.clj:105)
>           at bill.myquery$dump_db_csv__24.invoke(myquery.clj:27)
>           at bill.myquery$*main*_49.invoke(myquery.clj:41)
>           at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:171)
>           at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:164)
>           at bill.myquery.main(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted
>   Resultset
>           at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:47)
>           at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
>           at clojure.lang.Cons.next(Cons.java:37)
>           at clojure.lang.RT.boundedLength(RT.java:1128)
>           at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:135)
>           at clojure.core$apply__4370.invoke(core.clj:438)
>           at clojure.core$resultset_seq_*6276$thisfn*_6290$fn__6291.invoke(core.clj:3842)
>           at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
>           ... 8 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted
>   Resultset
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getObject(OracleResultSetImpl.java:900)
>           at clojure.core$resultset_seq__6276$row_values_*6284$fn*_6286.invoke(core.clj:3839)
>           at clojure.core$map_*5053$fn*_5055.invoke(core.clj:1760)
>           at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)

Here it is:

```
(ns bill.myquery (:gen-class))

;; Import java.sql classes
(import '(java.sql DriverManager Connection PreparedStatement ResultSet))

;; load jdbc/odbc driver
(. Class forName "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

(def dbname "myOracleServer:1522:myOracleDatabase")
(def service_account "account")
(def service_password "password")

(def conn (. DriverManager (getConnection (str "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" dbname) service_account service_password)))

(def sql "
        SELECT name, address, phone
        FROM addresss_book
        ORDER BY name")

;; Function to dump data with comma delimited fields
(defn dump-db-csv [db]
  (doseq [rec db] ;; for all rows
    (doseq [[key value] rec] ;; for all fields
        (if (= key :phone) ;; if last field
              (print (.trim (str value))) ;; don't print comma
              (print (format "%s%s" (.trim (str value)) ","))))
    (println)))

;; Execute query and get recordset
(def rs (.. conn (prepareStatement sql) (executeQuery)))

;; convert recordset to sequence
(def rset (resultset-seq rs))

;; Main call the function to print rows
(defn -main (dump-db-csv rset))

;; close the recordset
(. rs (close))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `def` - everything from the top level is executed at class load time (or even at compile time), so you close result set (`rs`) before running `-main`. Always open and close connection in a single function - it will prevent a lot of errors.

Also consider using [clojure.contrib.sql](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/sql-api.html). Nice examples can be found at [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/JDBC_Examples#Oracle).

For both methods don't forget to use `doall` for any possible lazy sequences.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that obvious mistake of closing the result set before running -main. I've never compiled Clojure before and overlooked that. I'm not sure what you mean by don't use def and why. Can you explain? I have used clojure.contrib.sql before but this program is so simple I didn't really feel the need. Thanks again.

Comment: First, you use imperative style, and Clojure is badly suited for it. For example, you cannot use [transients](http://clojure.org/transients) with imperative loops like `doseq`. And also with imperative style you loose all the power of lazy sequences, since they must be independent of a time of execution. See [this](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-20.html#%_sec_3.1) for more comprehensive example. Second, using `def` you introduce global variables, and that's a source of enormous number of errors. Put all your code to one `main` function and just call it at the end of file.

Comment: Also, for easier compiling consider using [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/). It's really easy-to-start tool which reduces your work on compiling to just several lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I took Andrei's advice and used clojure.contrib.sql. It does make this even more simple and less error prone. I still didn't want to give up def for the db and sql global variables.

Thanks Andrei

```
(ns my.query (:use [clojure.contrib.sql]))

(def *db* {:classname "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ; must be in classpath
           :subprotocol "oracle:thin"
           :subname "myserver:1521:mydatabase"
           ; Any additional keys are passed to the driver
           ; as driver-specific properties.
           :user "account"
           :password "password" })

(def *sql* "select * from phonebook")

(defn dump-db-csv []
  (with-connection *db*
    (transaction
      (with-query-results rs [*sql*]
          (doseq [row rs] ;; for all rows
            (doseq [[key value] row] ;; for all fields
                (if (= key :phone) ;; if last field
                  (print (.trim (str value))) ;; do not print comma
                  (print (format "%s%s" (.trim (str value)) ","))))
            (println))))))

;; Main - call the function to print rows
(dump-db-csv)
```